# Specific pattern to list files in R

Tags: r, regex

I have an issue when matching a very specific pattern when using list.files. I have a set of files with this pattern **"namefile_YYYY-mm-dd.csv"**, but also, if a file was generated more than one time then I will have something like this: **"namefile_YYYY-mm-dd_something-else.csv"**. This is what I used:

```
list.files(path = "\\projects\\datasets", pattern = "^Participants_(.*)csv$",all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)
```

This is the output: 
"Participants_2018-07-18.csv"
"Participants_2018-07-19.csv"
"Participants_2018-07-21.csv"
"Participants_2018-07-28.csv"
"Participants_2018-08-04 new.csv"
"Participants_2018-08-04.csv"
"Participants_2018-08-11.csv"
"Participants_2018-08-18 - for-analysis.csv"
"Participants_2018-08-18.csv"
"Participants_2018-08-25.csv"
"Participants_2018-09-01.csv"
"Participants_2018-09-08.csv"

But I don't want all of them. I would like the list includes only the names in this format **"Participants_2018-07-18.csv"** and exclude the names in any other format like this one: **"Participants_2018-08-04 new.csv"**, **"Participants_2018-08-18 - for-analysis.csv"**

I tried several things like

```
list.files(path = "\\projects\\datasets", pattern = "^Participants_[0-9]\\.csv$",all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)]
```

But the list came empty. Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may match those file names that only contain date-like pattern after `Participants_` by replacing `.*` with `\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}`:

```
list.files(path = "\\projects\\datasets", pattern = "^Participants_\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\.csv$",all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zG63aW/1).

The `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` regex pattern matches any four digtis, and then a sequence of `-` and any two digits twice.

Comment: Huge thanks! I tried a few different things and nothing, I guess I am still new with regex. Great suggestions. I am using both: replacing "participants" word with ".*" for something else I am working in same project, and the \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} for this specific task.